# sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net Issue With Full Size Profile Pictures

Tags: facebook, image, profile

I'm stuck with what is causing this issue. If i'm logged in as my account, the code below does not show user: 100000920350966 but if i logout & back into my wife's account I can now see that users profile picture.

Error I get logged into my FB account: 
http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/230962_10150332269178009_784368008_9751025_7802946_n.jpg

An example of one that does work:
http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/419763_10151360491990078_877370077_23594484_2739927_n.jpg

the code I am using is the PHP SDK and this piece for getting an image:

```
function randomUser() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT the_facebook_id FROM users WHERE the_facebook_id != '$facebook_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 mysql_close();
 return $result; }

$theuser = randomuser();


$albums = $facebook->api('/' . $theuser[0] . '/albums');
    foreach($albums['data'] as $album){
    if ($album['type'] == 'profile'){
    $photos = $facebook->api('/' . $album['id'] . '/photos');

    $random_pic = $photos['data'][0]['source'];

    }
}

echo "<br /><br />The User: " . $theuser[0] . "<br />";
echo "Photo Source: " . $photos['data'][0]['source'] . "<br />";
echo "THE PHOTO HEIGHT: " . $photos['data'][0]['height'] . "<br />";
echo "THE PHOTO WIDTH: " . $photos['data'][0]['width'] . "<br />";
```

I honestly have no idea what when in my account I can't see particular profile pictures but in my wife's I can see all of them. All help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: The urls of the images you posted should work for everyone, even if they are not logged into facebook, since those are urls of static images in the facebook CDN. Can you please explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? What permissions are you asking from the users?

Comment: I am asking for user photos, basics info like location, town, full name, DOB etc... nothing too extensive. It's really strange I know, but the code above is what I'm using...

I was wondering if it's got something to do with Access Tokens... there isn't much information on the net to get the full size images from peoples profiles.

Comment: Do you have an access token for the user, plus the needed [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to get his/his friends' photos (user_photos or friends_photos)?

Comment: I've got the following permissions on yet another testing site, which I know for sure has the Access Token. 
    'scope'   => 'email, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos, friends_photos',

thanks for your help so far, working through it. Check out www.thebeerscale.com - you can see I've now changed to an example I found tonight on a tutorial and I still get the Large Image issue on the right hand side (quickly added to test)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I tried that site and haven't noticed anything weird.

Comment: Check out my Firebug screenshot, maybe that will help. www.thebeerscale.com/screenshot.png

For instance, when I'm in my account, I can't see the full size profile picture of my wife, and our accounts are linked in terms of relationship so I'm not sure

Comment: The firebug print just shows a list of images, nothing that helps me understand the problem. What do you mean by "can't see"? don't you get it back from the fb api? or when you try to view the url you get an error?

Comment: The URL has the xx. problem and if you try too view that image you get an error. The images without xx. in the links work fine. I can view the smaller versions of these images fine though.

Comment: What error do you get? I can view this image for exapmle: http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/230962_10150332269178009_784368008_9751025_7802946_n.jpg and I don't get an error. How are you trying to view/get this image?

Comment: I get page cannot be displayed, like the address is wrong or dns issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case you've got there.

I can't tell you what's wrong, but I have a guess which is divided to two options.
The urls in question are for static content and so the content is not depended on the current user.
However, that url is of a cdn, which means that the copy of the content you get is different (probably) from the copy I get, which explains how is it that you're getting an error while I'm able see the picture for the same url.

The two options:

1. The cdn you are directed to is not available at all and so all images you ask from it will result in *page not found* error. Try to ping *sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net* and see what you get.
2. The cdn you are directed to does not have a copy of the image you are trying to get, maybe for some reason an error occurred when the file was supposed to propagate to the server.

This is just a guess of course, in any case I recommend you to [file a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and have the facebook team look it up, it might take some time for them to check it out/do something about it though.

Comment: That bug tool is for API bugs, a report for a problem with core functionality won't be accepted, for site bugs you should use the 'Known Issues' page at https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues?sk=app_4949752878

Comment: Hey guys, I've seen to overcome this issue, after heaps of googling there was another report of the same userid that was inserted into my database, it's not documented really anywhere but has to do with using BIG INT as INT isn't big enough, it also had something to do with the Access Token. Facebook API is not really well documented, they have crappy examples compared to something like the PHP examples and I honestly spend more time using var_dump or print_r than looking at the actual API... *curses Zuckerbergs name*